# Ubuntu 16.04 Black Screen After Suspend

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, suspend, power-management, shutdown

I've seen this issue reported but have not seen a solution working for me. I did a fresh install of 16.04 and everything is working great.

The only problem I'm having is when I close the lid on my laptop and open it back up later I just get a black screen. I hear the hardware working but the screen is completely black and the keyboard is unresponsive, other than the power button. I'm forced to do a hard shutdown by holding down the power button.

Does anyone know if anything is being done about this problem or if there area any ways around it (changing settings, installing anything, etc)? I leave my laptop on for long periods of time and it would be a huge pain to have to shut it down completely every time I'm finished using it for a while.

Laptop details:

- Lenovo L450
- i7 processor
- 8 GB Ram

This is dual boot laptop, I am not facing this issue on Windows 7.

Comment: I am having the same issue with 16.04; Lenovo Yoga 211, Linux Kernel 4.5, Pure Ubuntu + Openbox. I tried `apt install laptop-mode-tools` which has helped with some suspend/etc issues in 14.04... but no avail. I'll be searching for answers too. It's what we get for insisting on the newness of 16.04, but doesn't it feel good!

Answer (score 0):

What is the BIOS version you guys are running on your Lenovo machines? I think this may be related to a BIOS update in mid 2015. My G50-45 has the problem with this BIOS version, and it happens with kernels 3.18, 4.4, an 4.7 basically everything.

```
$ inxi -Fxz | grep Bios
Bios: LENOVO v: A2CN38WW(V2.06) date: 07/15/2015
```