# Ubuntu 16.04 black screen when shutdown / hibernate / restart

Tags: 16.04, suspend, power-management, shutdown, hibernate

Yes it's another one of those threads. There's so many of them but all quite outdated so I didnt want to screw up my machine by trying any grub based solution.

Basically, I just clean installed Ubuntu 16, and I can't shut down the laptop. Initially it was logging out instead of shutting down, so I did the logout fix.

Now, when I press shutdown, it goes into a black screen with a terminal like "_" at the top left corner, and it's frozen. I have to hard reset to shut it down.

Same goes if I close the lid, or press restart. `sudo shutdown` isnt working either.

Seen the below few threads, none of them really help.

[Ubuntu 16.04 hangs on shutdown/restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764568/ubuntu-16-04-hangs-on-shutdown-restart) <-- Interested in the second solution but I cant seem to locate and install just that update hes talking about?

[Ubuntu 16.04 Black Screen when waking from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774540/ubuntu-16-04-black-screen-when-waking-from-suspend)

[Ubuntu 16.04 Black Screen After Suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785157/ubuntu-16-04-black-screen-after-suspend)

Would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Specs:
Core i7 7700HQ
Nvidia 1060GTX (Currently disabled - running on intel graphics)

**EDIT**:

Tried [Ubuntu 14.04 stuck on shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508029/ubuntu-14-04-stuck-on-shutdown) as well but still nothing is working. Really no help guys?

**FURTHER EDIT**:
UPDATE:

I noticed NVIDIA PERSISTANCE DAEMON kept failing to load. If i do

`sudo prime-select nvidia` to switch to nvidia driver, I am able to shutdown / reboot via GUI. Command line still does not work.

Using intel graphics do not work though. Is there a solution?